# PYGAME initialize multiple objects at different times.

Tags: python, oop, object, pygame

I have a few objects scrolling across the screen. My only problem is that they start at the same time. I would like them to start at different times so that they arent always on the same X co ordinate. HOw would I do so?

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
winW = 800
winH = 500
surface = pygame.display.set_mode ((winW, winH),0,32)

class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, char, xMoveAmnt, startY=0, startX=0):
        self.char = char
        self.x = startX
        self.y = startY
        self.startX=startX
        self.startY=startY
        self.xMoveAmnt = xMoveAmnt
        self.image = pygame.image.load(self.char)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


    def moveChar(self):
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
        if self.x + self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.x=self.startX
            self.y=random.randint(0,300)


enemyList = []
for i in range (0, 3):
    xMoveAmnt=20
    enemyList.append(Enemy(("orc.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 500), 0))

while True:
    surface.fill ((255,255,255))
    for enemy in enemyList:
        enemy.moveChar()
        surface.blit(enemy.image, (enemy.x, enemy.y))
        time.sleep(00.01)        
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change that will have less impact in your code is to have another random parameter to your  initializer, that would specify a delay until the object starts to update itself.

```
class Enemy():
    def __init__(self, char, xMoveAmnt, startY=0, startX=0, delay=0):
         ...
         self.delay = delay

    def moveChar(self):
        if self.delay > 0:
             self.delay -= 1
             return
        self.x += self.xMoveAmnt
        if self.x + self.rect.right >= 800:
            self.x=self.startX
            self.y=random.randint(0,300)

enemyList = []
for i in range (0, 3):
    xMoveAmnt=20
    enemyList.append(Enemy(("orc.png"), xMoveAmnt, random.randint(0, 500), 0, random.randint(0,100)))
```

A few un-related hints:
1) don't use time.sleep - rather use pygame.time.delay for the timing
2) Learn about the sprite classes and sprite groups in Pygame before evolving the project
to something larger. They offer some higher level benefits for controling of multiple in game objects

Comment: Thank you so much! I will look into the sprite classes and groups when I decide to complicate this more. You helped me so much! :D